# Why save a html file in the database?

Tags: php, logic

I've inherited a project which saves the pages generated by php into database an then it calls them from a php controller on demand. I can't understand why they did this...

Comment: We don't know. Could be for caching (although there are probably better ways, e.g. just store the file on disk and send it directly to client or include it from PHP (but that all depends on various factors)). Ask them! We can only guess.

Comment: I wish I could... Caching yes it is possible...

Comment: Because they didn't know what they were doing ;-) Seriously though, I have no idea, although it is nice to think that there **must** have been a reason, probably not though... or for caching...

Comment: Yeah, unless it is for caching, it seems oddly suspicious to me as well.

Comment: If the content of the page doesn't change frequently, but generating the page is expensive, storing the output would be for cacheing purposes. Better to suck up a few kilobytes worth of database space than burn CPU time for every page request. But that presumes the cached page would be valid for more than a couple requests.

Comment: Perhaps if there are multiple webservers serving the pages, this could be an odd form of load balancing. Though of course, the database becomes a significant bottle neck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason to do this might be if generating the page is slow / computationally intense or if the generated result does not change very often. Storing the resulting HTML in a database sounds like some form of caching.

Also possible (though much less likely) is that they wanted to perform queries on the resulting HTML. This might make sense if the HTML contains the result of a long-running summary report. Searching for the summary data might be faster by searching the pre-generated HTML report rather than running a query directly against the data. I've seen similar things with XML data being stored and searched on, but not HTML.

Without *seeing* this particular project, it's hard for me to say any more...

Comment: +1 beat me by 20 seconds. I should have had my answer cached.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply a design decision.

Advantages that I can think of include

- it's easy to create a end-user interface to editing those pages.
- you don't have your file system cluttered with contents.
- A database backup is enough to save all user data - no additional file-system backups are necessary as long as you have the source project somewhere.

Still, in my personal opinion, it's usually a bad decision, especially if the code contains PHP that has to be `eval()` ed as well.

Stuff like this is often done in the (usually misguided) belief that serving stuff from the database is faster than serving stuff from the file system.

It's also bad for maintenance - if you're an outsider to a project, it's thousands of times more inconvenient to sift through a database, than through a nicely ordered file tree.

It will probably not be worth the effort to change how the inherited project works, so it's probably wise to just go on and try to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

*Probably for caching.* It might be quicker (in your case) to retrieve cached pages from the DB (1 query) than generating a whole new page (multiple queries).

Answer (score 0):

This likely was done as an attempt to improve application performance.  If the markup rendered from the script was intensive to produce (IE a lot of database calls, lengthy web service interactions) - then doing it once and "caching" the results would provide a speedier user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Caching and versioning. Check around they may bake the .html files daily too.